# Python pandas unique value ignoring NaN

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, null, unique

I want to use `unique` in `groupby` aggregation, but I don't want `nan` in the `unique` result.

An example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 1, 1, np.nan, 3, 3], 'b': [0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
    'c': ['foo', np.nan, 'bar', 'foo', 'baz', 'foo', 'bar']})

       a  b    c
0 1.0000  0  foo
1 2.0000  0  NaN
2 1.0000  1  bar
3 1.0000  1  foo
4    nan  1  baz
5 3.0000  1  foo
6 3.0000  1  bar
```

And the `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('b').agg({'a': ['min', 'max', 'unique'], 'c': ['first', 'last', 'unique']})
```

Its result is:

```
       a                             c                      
     min    max           unique first last           unique
b                                                           
0 1.0000 2.0000       [1.0, 2.0]   foo  foo       [foo, nan]
1 1.0000 3.0000  [1.0, nan, 3.0]   bar  bar  [bar, foo, baz]
```

But I want it without `nan`:

```
       a                        c                      
     min    max      unique first last           unique
b                                                           
0 1.0000 2.0000  [1.0, 2.0]   foo  foo            [foo]
1 1.0000 3.0000  [1.0, 3.0]   bar  bar  [bar, foo, baz]
```

How can I do that? Of course I have several columns to aggregate and every column needs different aggregation functions, so I don't want to do the `unique` aggregations one-by-one and separately from other aggregations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update 23 November 2020

This answer is terrible, don't use this. Please refer @IanS's answer.

#### Earlier

Try `ffill`

```
df.ffill().groupby('b').agg({'a': ['min', 'max', 'unique'], 'c': ['first', 'last', 'unique']})
```

```
      c                          a                 
  first last           unique  min  max      unique
b                                                  
0   foo  foo            [foo]  1.0  2.0  [1.0, 2.0]
1   bar  bar  [bar, foo, baz]  1.0  3.0  [1.0, 3.0]
```

If Nan is the first element of the group then the above solution breaks.

Comment: Thank all of you guys, I think [Bharath shetty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4800652/bharath-shetty) has the most simple and pythonic solution. Thanks again!!

Comment: This is a terrible solution. It is just plain wrong. It only happens to work for this example because the values above the NaNs happen to be in that group.

Comment: @Bharath I think this is actually a pretty good solution. It might not be the most elegant or pythonic, but I suspect it's faster than other options.

Comment: @ragesz please accept IanS's answer as it covers all edge cases. This answer doesn't hold good for many cases.

Answer (score 68):

Define a function:

```
def unique_non_null(s):
    return s.dropna().unique()
```

Then use it in the aggregation:

```
df.groupby('b').agg({
    'a': ['min', 'max', unique_non_null], 
    'c': ['first', 'last', unique_non_null]
})
```

Answer (score 5):

This will work for what you need:

```
df.fillna(method='ffill').groupby('b').agg({'a': ['min', 'max', 'unique'], 'c': ['first', 'last', 'unique']})
```

Because you use `min`, `max` and `unique` repeated values do not concern you.

Comment: also `df.ffill()..`

Comment: @Bharathshetty To be fair I saw zipa's answer appear first. Sometimes the timing at which answers appear is a bit random.

Comment: @Bharathshetty Didn't see it, but now that I do you got yourself a +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code,

```
    df.apply(lambda x: len(x.dropna().unique()))
```

Comment: This comment doesn't actually answer the question =/ it's specifically in a groupby context