# How do create lists of items for every unique ID in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, data-cleaning

Imagine I have a table that looks like this.

[original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXyBo.png)

How do I convert it into this?

[converted table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qv3B.png)

Attached sample data. Thanks.

Comment: Something like `df.groupby('id').agg(['unique'])`

Comment: Or `df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'name': 'first', 'fruit': 'unique', 'meat': 'unique'})`

Comment: Or if you want to exclude NaN/Missing values see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46218844/15497888)